# How to pass params to stack navigator from screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Is it possible to pass params from a React component or React Native screen to a react native screen navigator within a stack navigation.

The reason I would like to achieve this is the screen navigator has a button in it that needs to be passed a function.

So to be clear, I am using useState in a screen to save some values I am getting from a form. I would like to pass these values to the stack navigator so they can be used in a function that makes a call to an api.

[image]

Please note this question is not about passing params from screen to screen with React Navigation, I know how to achieve this using route params.

Comment: Please add enough code so that others can understand what you're trying to do and what you've tried so far.

Comment: From what you've said so far, it sounds like your stack navigator has too much responsibility. Why can't you make the API call on the screen where you have the data in state?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that if you hide the stack header & create your own header in the screen component, you can get all the parameters from **params**